# Sequelize coonection ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js

hay .. i using mysql with node.js using sequelize .. when i am runing in terminal

```
npm start..
```

the results like this

```
 > test@0.0.0 start /var/www/html/test
    > node src/

    info: Feathers application started on http://localhost:3030
    error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
      _bitField: 18087936,

  _fulfillmentHandler0: 
   { SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

i using Feathers.js for develop my app

this is file **database.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('project', 'root', 'test', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Koneksi Berhasil MEN!!!.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

please give me solution.. let NPM START is RUNNING....

Comment: It seems your mysql service is down, can you check the status of mysql ?

Comment: when i am check my status mysql is >>

Uptime: 753  Threads: 1  Questions: 113  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 153  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 146  Queries per second avg: 0.150

Comment: and mysql status is running